# S3 file upload file object using node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Sailsjs 0.12.1, node.js 4.2.6

I want to upload the file From front-end(angular.js) through an API and from backend I want to upload the file to the AWS S3 bucket.

front-end I'm sending the file to the api. In backend I'm getting the file with the name but while uploading the file to S3 I'm getting the error

> Cannot determine length of [object Object]

I google the error and found the many links but my bad luck.

Back-end

```
 uploadPersonAvtar: function(req, res) {
    var zlib = require('zlib');
    var file = req.file('image');
    var mime = require('mime');

    data = {
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key : 'my_key',
        Key: file.name,
        Body: file,
        ContentType: mime.lookup(file.name)
      };

    // Upload the stream
    var s3obj = new AWS.S3(S3options);
    s3obj.upload(data, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("An error occurred", err);
        console.log("Uploaded the file at", data);
    })
}
```

> Is my approach is correct
>
> If yes what I'm doing wrong.

I want to know how to use the file object to upload the file.
I can create a read stream but I don't have the file path When I'm creating the file object I'm getting the error: path must be a string

Comment: @Set its not just duplicate - the question here is "how to upload when you dont know the size of the file" technique is a bit different and you need to create a stream

Comment: @Set this is a different question I want to upload the file using file object

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [following example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html) about streaming data : *Amazon S3: Uploading an arbitrarily sized stream (upload)*

```
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var body = fs.createReadStream('bigfile').pipe(zlib.createGzip());
var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey'}});
s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
  on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
  send(function(err, data) { console.log(err, data) });
```

Comment: I'm using the file object so I'm getting the error "path must be a string"